# How to handle big column header to wrap on next line

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am using AGGrid in my React code and some of the column header Texts are too long , so when they are displayed I can not read the whole column header but I see few ...
Is there a way to wrap the header Text to next row without increasing the whole column width? I tried using setHEaderHeight. that does not wrap the text to next row.

```js
type Props = {
    comDto:CompDTO;
}
type State = {
}

const componentCssClass = componentStyle(`
    
    .ag-cell.fullText {
        white-space: normal;
        word-break: normal;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
    }      
`);

export class CompGrid extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {

    static compCols: Array<ColDef> = [
        {headerName: 'Market', field: 'marketType.marketName', width: 250},
        {headerName: 'My Role', field: 'myConfirmationRole', width: 150},
        {headerName: 'CP Matching', field: 'partyMatchingRole', width: 150},
        {headerName: 'BR Matching', field: 'MatchingRole', width: 150},
        {headerName: 'Reg Role', field: 'usRegRole', width: 150},
        {headerName: 'Create USIs on My Behalf', field: 'createUSIOnBehalf',
            cellRenderer: 'renderer_complistcheckbox'},
        {headerName: 'Voluntarily Report to MY Company', field: 'voluntaryReport', 
            cellRenderer: 'renderer_complistcheckbox'},
        {headerName: 'Use VICE DCO Valuation', field: 'useDCOValuations', width: 200,
            cellRenderer: 'renderer_comlistcheckbox'},
    ];

    private static gridComponents = {
        'renderer_complistcheckbox': CellRenderer_ReadOnlyCheckbox
    };

    render(){
        const {compDto} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={cx(flexAgGridContainerCss, componentCssClass)}>
                <AgDataGrid
                    frameworkComponents={ComGrid.gridComponents}
                    columnDefs={CompGrid.compCols}
                    suppressMovableColumns
                    suppressCellSelection
                    suppressRowHoverHighlight
                    rowData={compDto.marketRoles}
                    onGridReady={CompGrid.onGridReady}
                    onGridSizeChanged={CompGrid.onGridSizeChanged}
                    onColumnResized={CompGrid.onColumnResized}
                />
            </div>

        );
    }

    private static onGridReady(params) {
        const gridApi = params.api;
        gridApi.setHeaderHeight(30);
        gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit(); // for * size columns
    }

    private static onGridSizeChanged(params) {
        const gridApi = params.api;

        gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit(); // for * size columns
    }

    private static onColumnResized(params) {
        const gridApi = params.api;

        gridApi.resetRowHeights();  // for autoHeight...
    }


}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code or ss ?

Comment: I edited my post with code snippet

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, You are looking for `autoSizeColumn()`.

```
.
.
let ColumnApi;
.
.
onGridReady= (gridApi, columnApi ) => {
    gridApi.setHeaderHeight(30);
    gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    ColumnApi = columnApi;
    this.autoSizeColumn();
};

autoSizeColumn = () => {
    let allcolumn = [];
    ColumnApi.getAllColumns().forEach((column) => {
        allcolumn.push(column.colId);
    });
    ColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allcolumn);
}
```

You can call this `autoSizeColumn ();` from where you add your rows. Its basicly rearrange the column header size for row that has max width, makes your column header size.

Note: `autoSizeColumn` function doesnt change the columns headers that are not visible in the page.

For more info and documents you can check [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#auto-size-columns) link

Comment: This did not solve my issue. What I need is If the data inside a cell is too lengthy , then instead of showing it as .... it should wrap to next line and the user should be able to view the entire content of the row.